# Buildr - exclude directory from resources

Tags: buildr

In Buildr you can exclude all files in a directory by doing the following:

```
resources.exclude 'scratch/*'
```

Is it possible to exclude the directory as well? The Buildr documentation mentions:

> The filter always excludes the CVS and .svn directories, and all files
>   ending with .bak or ~, so no need to worry about these.

My company uses Dimensions as its source control, it creates a .metadata folder in every directory much like subversion does with the .svn folder.

Answer (score 0):

These exclusions are actually inherited from Rake (rake/file_list.rb)

```
module Rake
  ...
  class FileList
    ...

    DEFAULT_IGNORE_PATTERNS = [
      /(^|[\/\\])CVS([\/\\]|$)/,
      /(^|[\/\\])\.svn([\/\\]|$)/,
      /\.bak$/,
      /~$/
    ]

    ...
  end
end
```

so it's possible to monkey-patch the defaults, if that's what you want.

Alternatively, you can also add exclusions directly on a `FileList` by passing a block and calling the `exclude` method,

```
pkg_files = FileList.new('lib/**/*') do |fl|
  fl.exclude(/\bCVS\b/)
end
```

Since Buildr filters (http://buildr.apache.org/rdoc/classes/Buildr/Filter.html) expose their underlying `FileList`, you can simply do:

```
resources.sources do |fl|
  fl.exclude(/\.metadata/)
end
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work (sorry lack of Ruby skills letting me down). resources.sources do... doesn't do anything for me (prob missing something simple) and pkg_files = FileList...filters out the correct Files and directories but I can't seem to tell resources to include pkg_files